# Converting Tree to Json using Jackson without having square braces and field names

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have following tree structure in Java (-> denotes parents of)

Node A -> Node B

Node B -> Node C

Node C -> Node D

Node C -> Node E

I have following class to represent the Tree

```
    class TreeNode{
       private String name;
       private List<TreeNode> children;
    }
```

And now when I serialise the data to Json, I wish to have the following output.

```
    {
      "A": {
        "B": {
          "C": {
            "D": {},
            "E": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have managed to used custom serializer to remove the field names, however, the current response I receive has square brackets and I am not sure how to remove these.

Current output I get

```
     {
      "A": [
        {
          "B": [
            {
              "C": [
                {
                  "D": []
                },
                {
                  "E": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Serialiser I implemented

```
class TreeNodeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<TreeNode> {
        @Override
        public void serialize(Sample2Test.TreeNode value,
                              JsonGenerator gen,
                              SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeObjectField(value.getName(), value.getChildren());
            gen.writeEndObject();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @azurefrog sorry, was a typo. Fixed it.

Comment: Maybe show your serialization code ?

Comment: @AliceOualouest done, thanks!

Comment: Normally your objects would look like `{"name":"something", "children":[...]}` as JSON, even what you have now looks like a hack already, and what you aim for would be "hacker".

Comment: I'm fairly confident `"D": [], "E": []` is not part of a possible output of this code

Comment: @njzk2 you are right, fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The core issue is that here

```
gen.writeObjectField(value.getName(), value.getChildren());
```

`value.getChildren()` is a `List<Node>`. So, the serializer serializes it as an Array, and then comes back to the custom serializer `TreeNodeSerializer` to serialize each children.

I don't quite understand how you get

```
            {
              "D": [],
              "E": []
            }
```

Since you only ever write one key to the object, so I expect it should be

```
            {
              "D": []
            },
            {
              "E": []
            }
```

instead.

To solve this, you need to actually serialize the children as well:

```
gen.writeFieldName(value.getName());
gen.writeStartObject();
for (Node child: value.getChildren()) {
    gen.writeObjectField(child.getName(), child);
}
gen.writeEndObject();
```

However, you can now see that the name of the child is there twice, in the parent serialization and in it's own serialization.

So, you can remove it from itself, but you're left with the issue of solving for the root, meaning you'd need something like a root node that contains your node A.

Which makes sense, as nothing prevents your root object right now from having multiple keys in it, except your structure doesn't allow for it.

So, the final method should be:

```
gen.writeStartObject();
for (Node child: value.getChildren()) {
    gen.writeObjectField(child.getName(), child);
}
gen.writeEndObject();
```

And create a dummy root node to hold your actual root(s) node(s)

Answer (score 0):

Squara brackets in JSON (aka JavaScript) represent lists (aka arrays).

You didnt' provide the code for your serializator, but I'm guessing that you are simply adding children - which is a `List`.

Instead of a `List`, you shoud be putting a `Map` where keys are children's names and values are children's children. Of course, this will only work if your names are unique.

Comment: Added Serializer to the original question, thanks!